# React-navigation imported but undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

My react-native application uses react-redux and react-navigation.

App.js imports `Main` component. Inside `Main`, react-navigation is imported and all the navigators are defined. However, I still get **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'that.navigation.navigate')]** on `that.navigation.navigate('Auth')` in `Main`.

I have also tried `navigation.navigate('Auth')` but got **Can't find variable: navigation**. Is it a bad practice to import react-navigation and use it within the same file? I'd like to use navigation in `Main` to avoid calling `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` in every screen.

App.js

```
...

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

...

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    var that = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
        if (user) {
            await that.props.getUserProfile(user.uid);
        } else {
            that.navigation.navigate('Auth');
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      user: state.auth.user
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getUserProfile})(Main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I never used react navigation
But it seems like only AppContainer and his children are wrapped and not Main Component, that's should be why navigation is undefined here.
You should re-think your component architecture order

---

Form https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

> Each screen component can set navigation options such as the header title. It can use action creators on the `navigation` prop to link to other screens

Your `Main` Component is not a screen, you cannot use navigation in it.

You can do something like that :

```
const AppContainer = isAuthentified => createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(
 {
  Home: HomeStack,
  Auth: AuthStack
 },
 {initialRouteName: !!isAuthentified ? 'Home' : 'Auth'}
)); 


class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   state = {loading: false};
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
   let tmpuser = false; 
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
    if (user) {
        tmpuser = await that.props.getUserProfile(user.uid);
    }});
   this.setState({user: tmpuser, loading: false})
  }

  render() {
   if (!this.state.loading) 
    return (
     <div>{AppContainer(this.state.user)}</div>
    );
   else return (<div>loading</div>);
  }
}
```

//Can be not perfect, done on smartphone

Comment: Yes I could call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` in one of my screens in the Home stack but then it is called everytime I go to a new screen. The reason for having `Main` here is to call the function only once

Comment: MainStack is a switch navigator, not sure how you plan on doing it in there?

Comment: I don't think you are talking about the same thing, I need to call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` somewhere, it cannot be done in MainStack because it is just a navigator

Comment: Can you put this in your answer, it's hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

You for got props.

Change `that.navigation.navigate('Auth');`
to `that.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');`

Comment: Doesn't work; navigation isn't passed from props in this case